# Is $St(n,R) \rightarrow St(n+1,R)$ injective?

Tags: k-theory, algebraic-k-theory

For every (not necessarily commutative) ring R and every $n\geq 3$, one can define the n-th (unstable) Steinberg group St(n,R) as in https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Steinberg+group. Is the canonical map  $St(n,R) \rightarrow St(n+1,R)$ injective?

Comment: I can't think of a counterexample, but all the literature I've read on this topic seems to (tacitly) assume no: the inclusions aren't necessarily injective.